# Excel 2013 64bit VBA syntax error "Compile error: "Expected: End of Statement"

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

I have the following code, which gives me the Compile error: "Expected: End of Statement" in the Subject line of code after the "Inc" **Range**.

This code is part of a module which opens MS Outlook email and enters data from specific cells in the data sheet (generated from a Userform) in to the Subject field of the email.

The code:

```
'This bit tells it where to send the email to, what the subject line is etc
    .to = "princess_ingelise@yahoo.co.uk"
    .CC = "princess_ingelise@yahoo.co.uk"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Inc" Range("H6").Value & " " & Range("G12").Value & " - " & Range("G14").Value & " " & Range("H8").Value
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Display

   End With
   On Error GoTo 0
```

Is this sufficient information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check if it's because is missing the "&" operator

```
.Subject = "Inc"  Range("H6").Value & " " & Range("G12").Value & " - " & Range("G14").Value & " " & Range("H8").Value
```

Should be

```
.Subject = "Inc" & Range("H6").Value & " " & Range("G12").Value & " - " & Range("G14").Value & " " & Range("H8").Value
```

Comment: `On Error Goto 0` reset the error handler to its default, why do you think it isn't good practice?

Comment: Corrected my previous message, I read some documentation and you are right (here http://analystcave.com/vba-proper-vba-error-handling/) about is the only way to reset the error handler. Thanks for correcting me. @VincentG

Comment: Thank you (apologies for the delay in response.